# Convert titlesec titleformat to KOMA Script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, titlesec, scrreprt

Im quite new to Latex and i have created a document template based on several code snippets. The result looks not that bad but now i switched to KOMA Script scrreprt class. Not my titlesec part is not any longer "supported".

I have the following code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\usekomafont{chapter}}%
{\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
        {\color{chaptercolor}%
            \rule[-5pt]{1mm}{5cm}}\quad%
        {\color{chaptercolor}
            \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
}%
{-1.8em}%
{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}%
[\phantomsection]


\titlespacing*{\section}{0mm}{8mm}{3mm}
```

I would like to create an equivalent result with KOMA-Script compatible code. Can anyone help me to rewrite the sections?

I think the only part that must be changes is `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%` and `\titlespacing*{\section}{0mm}{8mm}{3mm}` true?

Im thankfull for every input you give to me. 
Thank you.

Here is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the my answer to your other question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491316/43317.

Comment: Perfectly :) Thank you!